# Is it possible to convert or map a string to a type?

Tags: typescript

What I would like to do is something like this pseudocode:

```js
const resourceTypeMap = {
  CodeSystem: fhir4.CodeSystem // string represents the desired type
}
```

I'm trying to write a factory to return a strongly typed resource object. What I'm trying to avoid is having a big switch statement to create resources of different types.

Obviously I can't use a namespace as a type, or I could just do:

```js
const resource: fhir4['CodeSystem'] = {};
```

Thanks to @kelsny for getting me on the right track with the type:

```js
export type IResourceTypeToFHIRTypeMap = {
  CodeSystem: fhir4.CodeSystem,
  Library: fhir4.Library,
  ObservationDefinition: fhir4.ObservationDefinition,
  PlanDefinition: fhir4.PlanDefinition,
  TestScript: fhir4.TestScript,
  Questionnaire: fhir4.Questionnaire,
  ValueSet: fhir4.ValueSet,
}
```

What I'd like to do now is derive a type that is a discriminated union of all of the types in `IResourceTypeToFHIRTypeMap`.

I need to end up with a type that is:

```js
fhir4.CodeSystem
| fhir4.Library
| fhir4.ObservationDefinition
| fhir4.PlanDefinition
| fhir4.TestScript
| fhir4.Questionnaire
| fhir4.ValueSet
```

I could maintain this as a type literal from an enum, but I'm wondering if there's a way to derive it from the existing type.

Comment: I don't see any strings. Is `fhir4.CodeSystem` supposed to be the string, or the final type after the transformation? It's really unclear how you want to do the mapping, too.

Comment: @kelsny the string is the key of the `resourceTypeMap` object in the pseudocode. I would like to be able to look up , map, etc, a type via a string representation.

Comment: Are you asking for this then https://tsplay.dev/WKK2GW

Comment: @kelsny that appears to work. I feel like doing a double facepalm at the moment... I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: Given your edited example, you could use `typeof fhir4['CodeSystem']`

Comment: Yes. I think I can get on the right track now.

Comment: @kelsny can you help with the update to my question?

Comment: `IResourceTypeToFHIRTypeMap[keyof IResourceTypeToFHIRTypeMap]`

Comment: @kelsny I was so close. Thanks a million. If you add that as an answer, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Actually, @kelsney, that gets me a union of the keys... I need a union of the types

Comment: `IResourceTypeToFHIRTypeMap[keyof IResourceTypeToFHIRTypeMap]` not `keyof IResourceTypeToFHIRTypeMap`

Comment: @kelsny I'm not following... that's the same code as your previous comment

Comment: Actually, I think I may be mistaken on how the TS interpreter is displaying the type in IntelliSense. It's omitting the `fhir` portion of the type. I made a quick union of the expected types and its also drops the `fhir` portion

Comment: Yes, namespaces that are accessible to you (i.e., you are able to directly reference them by name) will have their names be omitted from the display.